# Sub-domain hosting on a different server

Tags: iis, dns, subdomain

I have a domain with wildcard - *.mysite.com hosted on Server1

I am planning to host a sub-domain - sales.mysite.com on Server2.

Is this achievable? If yes I have a couple of questions on this.

1. How does DNS know to which server to point when sales.mysite.com is requested?
2. Does all traffic come to the Server1 and then redirected to Server2 if the destination calls for sales.mysite.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is very easy to achieve. you need to configure your dns server that subdomain.mydomain.com points to server 1 and subdomain2.mydomain.com points to server 2. the traffic won't be routed via server 1. it will directly go to server 2. thats how DNS works. In the DNS server for each domain an ip address is stored. you just need to specify your 2 ip addresses the correct way for the subdomains and it should work. more infos you can get from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System